# Store properties file in map

Tags: java, dictionary, properties, config

I want to read a usual properties file and put the attribute and his value into a Map object.
Technically, a properties file like

```
attr1=hello
attr2=java
attr3=world
```

would dynamically become a map object like this

```
+-------+-------+
+   K   |   V   +
+-------+-------+
+ attr1 | hello +
+-------+-------+
+ attr2 | java  +
+-------+-------+
+ attr3 | world +
+-------+-------+
```

In the end, it shouldn't matter what's in the properties file, the whole file will just be saved as a Map.
Is it possible to do that with java.Properties or is a FileReader or an InputStream with special parsing necessary?

Comment: `java.util.Properties` is also implementation of `Map`. Use Properties' `load()` method with reader or input stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.Properties` also implements of `Map`.

To load the properties from file, use Properties' `load()` method with `Reader` or `InputStream`.

For instance,

```
Properties config = new Properties();
try {
    config.load(<this.class>.getResourceAsStream(<property-file-name>)); //example input stream
    //now can access it as a Map instance
    config.get(<Key>);
    config.entrySet();

    //additionally, you can access Properties methods
    config.getProperty(<property-name>);

} catch(...) {
    ...
}
```

If you want only `Map` instance, let's say kind of `Map<String, String>`, need to convert the properties to required map instance by iterating the property names.

```
Properties config = new Properties();
try {
    config.load(<this.class>.getResourceAsStream(<property-file-name>)); //exampl input stream

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (final String name: config.stringPropertyNames())
        map.put(name, config.getProperty(name));

} catch(...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, but it doesn't solve my problem. I need the map to create my UI. Every key is a title, every value is a part of the content. Therefore, the access should be dynamic, so I can create my GUI just by specifying the Map. Could you edit your answer for this purpose?

Comment: @muffin Yes, `Properties` implementation is kind of `Map<Object, Object>`, so it can be problem in UI population. I've updated the answer and try it with and let me know the result.