# Creating a map in config files

Tags: java, scala, configuration, config, configuration-files

We have one application where we use configuration files and they have fields as arrays and normal variables:

```
metadata {
   array=["val1", "val2"]
   singleValue=2.0
}
```

Now, I know how to extract these above values like

```
config.getStringList("metadata.array").asScala.toArray
```

and `config.getString("metadata.singleValue)`

But, is there any way I can define maps here so that I can find value wrt desired key from that map.
This `config` is an object of
 `public interface Config extends com.typesafe.config.ConfigMergeable`

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking

Comment: Does this topic help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280226/store-properties-file-in-map

Comment: You can use `config.getConfig("metadata")` to obtain a (sub)config object. Converting that to a map is something you'll have to do yourself. entrySet (https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html#entrySet--) might be helpful for the purpose.

Comment: @JackLeow you should post that as an answer!

Comment: @Dici In simple words, I want to create a map in config file and get that map in code file so I can get value for desired keys.

Comment: @BozhidarGanev Nopes, I don't want to treat entire file as a map.

Comment: @JackLeow , I am trying to get it done by your solution, Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [config.getConfig("metadata")](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html#getConfig-java.lang.String-) to obtain a (sub)config object.

Converting the (sub)config to a map is something you'll have to do yourself. I would use [config.entrySet()](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html#entrySet--) to obtain the entries as key-values, and load it into a map that way.

I haven't tried compiling/testing this code, but something like this should work:

```
Map<String,Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,ConfigValue> entry : config.entrySet()) {
    metadata.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().unwrapped());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning it again here. It is the desired solution :)